# use spark SQL udf in dataframe API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

How can I use a UDF which works great in spark like

```
sparkSession.sql("select * from chicago where st_contains(st_makeBBOX(0.0, 0.0, 90.0, 90.0), geom)").show
```

taken from from http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/spark/sparksql.html 
via spark`s more typesafe scala dataframe API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a function, you can register the created UDF using:

```
sparksession.sqlContext.udf.register(yourFunction)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Oliviervs  I think he's looking for something different.  I think Georg wants to use the udf by string in the `select` api of the dataframe. For example:

```
val squared = (s: Long) => {
  s * s
}
spark.udf.register("square", squared)

df.select(getUdf("square", col("num")).as("newColumn")) // something like this
```

Question in hand is if there exists a function called `getUdf` that could be utilized to retrieve a udf registered via string.  Georg, Is that right?

Comment: ;) actually I have a library (geospark) and that registers some functions, but discards / does not store the references returned by `sparksession.sqlContext.udf.register` and I wonder how to get them back, i.e. to not have to rely  on random strings.